# How to test call twice get method in a spock test framework

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am new to Spock.now I have a twice get Method in the source Java Method, I wrote the code, but always get the NP exception.Anyone can help to see.

```
    def "check call outMethid2"(){
        given:
        def mockAppointRuleService = Mock(IAppointRuleService)
        def mockService = Mock(AppDomainContext)
        mockService.getBean(_,_ as Class) >> mockAppointRuleService
        def userDTO = new UserDTO(name: "chendd")
        mockAppointRuleService.usxx(_) >>  userDTO

        when:
        IAppointRuleService appointRuleService = AppDomainContext.getBean("eh.appointRuleService", IAppointRuleService.class)
        def resutl = appointRuleService.usxx()

        then:
        resutl == userDTO
    }
```

I wish to get the userDTO,but also nullpointeException

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and edit your question in order to create one. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you should call `getBean(...)` on `mockService` rather than on `AppDomainContext` in `when:` block. Also, I don't quite understand what is being tested here unless it's a synthetic example. Or you are testing the Spock mocking functionality. In other words, the code (behaviour) under test is missing here